# dimple tooltip too wide

Tags: jquery-mobile, tooltip, dimple.js

I am using dimple.js on a mobile device but when the text is too long for the tool tip is just goes off the screen instead of wrapping down. Is there a way to set a maximum width for the tooltip? I am currently using this code to show only certain info:

```
s.getTooltipText = function (e) {
return [
 "Product Description: " + e.aggField[0],
 "Volume: " + e.yValue
];
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty way would be just to use CSS:

```
.dimple-tooltip{
    width: 200px !important;   
}
```

Note that this won't auto-wrap text though.

Comment: Adding that style did change the width of the tool tip but the text now sticks outside the tooltip. i know you said it wouldnt auto-wrap the text but do you know of anyway that I can?